# Long notification delay after positive reputation change

Tags: discussion, reputation, notifications

On Stack Overflow, when I get a positive reputation change, it takes a long time to get the green +XX. So far, all of my positive rep changes (3 upvotes, 1 accept) for the UTC day have been delayed by completely random times. My last upvote took 6 minutes, the second last took 17 minutes. Yesterday (UTC), all the way up to 23:32 UTC, this was **not** happening.

I'm attributing it to the pomp I'm wearing my hat with right now, but, I don't feel like SO should chastise me like this just be I'm wearing a glorious hat like it should be worn...

Anyone else noticing something similar?

Comment: 7 views after 30 minutes on meta! Strange.

Comment: It stopped happening almost as soon as I opened this question, I'm sorry to have forgotten to note. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: user17242583, Thank you for the update, I'm going to vote to close this as: "No longer reproducible - 
The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.".